# Inner Product (Matrix multiplication) in convolution Layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, keras, multiplication

I want to find inner product (matrix product)  between feature maps of the same CNN layer. I have created a custom layer to do thisand  tried to apply 'matmul' operation between the layers, But I end up getting errors. Please assist on what I should do.

> ValueError: 'dim' input must be a tensor with a single value for 'inner_product2__test_16/ExpandDims' (op: 'ExpandDims') with input shapes: [2,?,200,240,128], [2] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <-2 -1>.

My codes for Custom Layer are:

```
# Custom Inner Product Layer of 4D tensor
class InnerProduct2_Test(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim='4+')]
        self.out_dim = None
        super(InnerProduct2_Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        """ Build the model based on input shape: """
        assert len(input_shape) == 2
        assert input_shape[0] == input_shape[1]
        self.out_dim = input_shape[1]
        self.built == True
    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        if not all(input_shape[1:]):
            raise Exception('Number of inputs is supposed to be two bu found another value')
        assert input_shape[0] == input_shape[1]
        return input_shape
    def get_config(self):
        '''No any configuration file for now'''
    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        """
        4D tensor with same shape as input
        """
        if K.backend() == 'theano':

            raise ValueError("InnerProduct not supported for Theano")
        else:
            if self.built:
                import tensorflow as tf
                inner = tf.expand_dims(x,(-2,-1))
                Product = tf.matmul(inner, inner)
                return Product
            else:
                raise RuntimeError("Something is wrong")'''
```

Applying the inner prouct on the CNN:

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Lambda,Flatten,Softmax,dot, 
Activation,Cropping2D
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Model,Input
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.engine import Layer, InputSpec

InputsL=Input(shape=(200,240,3))
x=Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')(InputsL)
x=InnerProduct2_Test()([x,x])
x=Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same')(x)
x=MaxPooling2D(2,2)(x)
x=InnerProduct2_Test()([x,x])
x=Activation('softmax')(x)
x=Cropping2D((2,2))(x)
x=InnerProduct2_Test()([x,x])
x=Flatten()(x)
Model2=Model(inputs=inputsL,outputs=x)
`'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Tensor multiplication is just a generalization of matrix multiplication which is just a generalization of vector multiplication.

Matrix multiplication is defined as:

⋅=,
where  is the ℎ row,  is the ℎ column, and ⋅ is the dot product. Therefore it just a series of dot products.

One can then see how this extends to tensors:
⋅=,
where  is the ℎ row-wise matrix of the tensor, and  is the ℎ column-wise matrix of the tensor... and is therefore just a series of matrix multiplications - or a series of a series of dot products.

Assuming all tensors are of rank three(it can be described with three coordinates):

⊗=,⋅,=,,
which means the (,)ℎ vector of  times the (,)ℎ vector of .
As for you your error is showing some programmatic mistake not in logic.. you better implement 
inner = tf.expand_dims(x,(-2,-1))
this function usage from documentation provided by python and tensor core 
in here
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims

Comment: thanks  @Uroosa,
Can you please send me the sample codes which work properly on my problem???